# os.popen strange codec issue

Tags: python, shell, cmd, symbols, popen

So im trying to use os.popen to run cmd comands, but the problem is that most of the comands have cyrillic characters in them that seem to have some issues with os.popen. When i use this code

```
import os

stream = os.popen("dir")
output = stream.read()
print(output)
```

I get output like this:

[image]

And i need to get output like this:

[image]

Also i tried to do this with subprocess library but it is much harder to work with subprocess library and i couldnt get encoding done correctly after really long time so i really want to do this with os library if it is possible.

Comment: Can you run `chcp` in command prompt and post the output?

Comment: @SuperStormer If i do this `stream = os.popen("chcp")` , i get this `’ҐЄгй п Є®¤®ў п бва ­Ёж : 866`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how to make `os.popen` use a specific encoding(and I don't think its possible), so here is a solution using subprocess:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.run("dir", shell=True, encoding="cp866", stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
print(output)
```

Edit: dir is a shell builtin, so you need `shell=True`, but you can use a list arg for normal commands.

Comment: It says it can't find needed file when i do `"dir"`, but it worked when i tried more complex command `["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile"]` that i plan to use this script for it worked! Thanks a lot for the solution!

Comment: Oops, `dir` might be a shell builtin.